# Training recommendations for Continuous Integration and TestComplete

Tags: training, continuous-integration

At my company we use a lot of custom built tools, our Continuous Integration is also custom built and my job is it to drive the development further and to implement automated tests in TestComplete for our latest applications that change daily. The GUI is now quite stable and will not be changed a lot anymore I hope.

I have not seen other Continuous Integration tools like Jenkins yet. We there is a Submit in our CI, the code is compiled and if this is successful it is tested with my tests also. I splitted them into different phases.

Starting the application
Doing basic interaction like changing layouts
Exiting the application and collecting log files and dump files that might have been created

I have the possibility to attend a training that is paid by the company each year. What training would you recommend to me?

Answer (score 2):

We use Jenkins to orchestrate our CI and Continuous Delivery.

This training course looks pretty good: http://www.cloudbees.com/training.cb

Comment: The trainings are only for Java ecosystems, is there something similar for C++ ecosystems?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for TestComplete training, you probably want to look at the SmartBear website (http://www.smartbear.com). They have a number of webinars available at any time. There's also more intense training available: http://smartbear.com/products/qa-tools/automated-testing-tools/features/training-certification/

I've never done any of the training myself, but I know people who have and they found it very helpful.